# Password Reset functionality inheriting from Django clases - reverse url issues ('uidb64')

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I want to create a Password Reset functionality but changing the templates.
So I'm inheriting from Django classes.

After I insert the email to reset password, I ge the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password-reset/
>
> Reverse for 'confirm_reset_password' with keyword arguments
>   '{'uidb64': '', 'token': '4y5-9ae986836e35f95b842c'}' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried:
>   ['accounts\/password-reset-confirm/(?P[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']

I think the issue is that 'uidb64', but I don't know why is empty.

Views:

```
class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):

    form_class = CustomPasswordResetForm
    email_template_name = 'account/password_reset_email.html'
    template_name = 'account/password_reset.html'

class UserPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):

    pass
```

Form:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=TextInputWidget)
```

Urls:

```
path('password-reset/', UserPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),

re_path(r'^password-reset-confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
UserPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='confirm_reset_password')
```

in reset template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row ">
    {{ form.email }}
  </div>
  <div class="l-action">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Reset my password">
  </div>
</form>
```

In email template:

```
a href="http://{{ domain }}{% url 'users:confirm_reset_password' uidb64=uidb token=token %}"
```

Comment: The `uidb64` is empty? According to your `re_path`, it should contain *at least* one character.

Comment: @Sugumar - yes, the others User related views works

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes but shouldn't PasswordResetconfirm generate uidb64 ?

Comment: @user3531631: it does, but it stores it in `uid`, not `uidb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your email template contains an error. You write:

```
a href="http://{{ domain }}{% url 'users:confirm_reset_password' uidb64=uidb token=token %}"
```

But the `uidb64` parameter should, according to the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) have as parameter the `uid` variable, so:

```
a href="http://{{ domain }}{% url 'users:confirm_reset_password' uidb64=uid token=token %}"
```

Comment: @user3541631: I think you need to use the `html_email_template_name` (well both, such that it generates a multipart email). Since some email clients do *not* render HTML, it is safer to also include a "text-only" version.